# Linux Command: How to move files from a directory to another with waiting a few seconds

Tags: linux, shell

Could someone tell me how to move (or copy) files from a directory to another one with waiting a few seconds between a copy and the next ?!

(using linux commands)

i.e. the execution sequence should be as follows:

```
move file1
sleep n
move file2
sleep n
...
```

thanks for help

Comment: Why do you want to wait a few seconds between each move?

Comment: `mv` to move, `sleep` to sleep and `for f in $(ls dir)...` to iterate.

Comment: @John Kugelman it is a use case of my application !

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question. Why is it a use case? What is the purpose of the delays?

Comment: @John Kugelman - I'm coding a Streaming application that needs to read files each time interval...

Answer (score 2):

```
mv /old/dir/file1 /new/dir/
sleep 5
mv /old/dir/file2 /new/dir/
sleep 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't know the name of all files, I've to proceed like this:

```
for f in dir1/*
do
  mv $f dir2/
  sleep 2
done
```

Comment: [Don't parse output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Do: `for f in dir1/*; do echo "$i"; done`